# Need to affix an outdoor boiler to an external wall that has started to come away

Tags: walls, heating, screws, mounting

I have a situation where an existing boiler that was fixed to an external weatherboard wall has started to come loose.  The weatherboard had some dry-wall or something affixed first to which the boiler was actually attached.  The screws that held the brackets in place at the top of the boiler area have come loose (assuming that over time the elements have got to the wood underneath and it has started to rot or weaken and the thread of the screw no longer 'screwed' into it.

I am now wanting to use a new bracketing system to attach the top part of the boiler back to the wall (dry-wall) as a intermediate fix until one day when I replace the whole boiler system over.

My question is which type of brackets and screws would I need to do such a job.  I was thinking a simple bracket that is long enough to affix the top of the boiler external metal frame to the dry-wall. something like a L shaped bracket with enough length to fill the gap (i.e from the wall and the Unit external casing when sitting 'upright'.

The photos attached show the current situation, where the boiler is leaning outward (not good as I assume if left like this long enough it will rip itself of the wall and cause more damage)

[image: Bracket potential mounting area]
The orange line is where potential bracket could be, note that the tin square sheet in picture is just to indicate what it may look like

[image: Current state of problem]
Current state of problem
[image: Where existing fixings have come undone]
This is where the existing screws have come undone

[image: 'dry-wall' attached to weatherboard wall]
This is the sheet that was attached to the weatherboard wall to affix the boiler unit I assume when first built.  This sheet is still sturdy and fixed to the wall

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Ze1.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt those screws ever went into wood - they look too short. They appear to have only been holding in the sheet of whatever. They appear to be self-drilling sheetmetal screws or something similar. For a "temporary quick fix" I'd support the bottom outer edge of the boiler from the ground surface. *i.e.* a stack of bricks.

Comment: The problem is the foundation that should be supporting the boiler, but isn't.
this is is causing it to lean away from the wall.

Comment: @Jasen this boiler is actually a wall mounted model, the pictures don't show but underneath the boiler body/frame is a gap of about (4-5 bricks:)) There is also another bracket from the lower part of the boiler that connects it to the same sheet on the wall - the only part that may provide some support from the ground are two pipes which are probably to take in/out water supply to and from the radiators inside the house.  I have more photos but basically I think I need to re-screw the frame into that sheet

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks I have propped it up from the bottom on a stack of bricks as an intermediate fix.

Comment: those top brackets don't look like they were designed to support any weight, (or possibly they were installed wrong)  wha's going on at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @Jasen, these are the fixings at the bottom, not sure how well they ever supported the weight, however it has gotten worse over the past 2 years since I have been here - I will add more photos to illustrate the two brackets at the bottom with similar screws & a small bracket holding an overflow container to the wall